Spring Repository - Is it OK creating a @Repository class only for a specific stored procedure?
I have to call a stored procedure in my project and it requires:

validation if a temp database exists
create this temp db if needed
execute insert statements in this temp db
call stored procedure passing a lot o parameters
make a select in the resultset returned by stored procedure
drop temp table

Is it ok(in architectural point of view, good pratice, abd so on) to create a @Repository class only for "mapping" this stored procedure "behaviour"?
I've created a @Reository class only for this soterd procedure because his "behaviour" is a lit bit long...but I'm not sure if it's the better approach

What alternative would you implement if not a repository? What do you think are the pros and cons of each approach?

Probably a DAO (@Component)
Pros:
dao -> I've a class only for stored procedure bahaviour and, it wouldn't increase
size of other repositories...a repository could use my dao
repository -> it works and my manager dont care about good pratices :)
Cons:
dao -> not sure exactly...maybe a generic dao for a generic sp behaviour
should be "acceptable"
repository -> it doesn't seem to be correct create a repository only for a stored
procedure, repositories should be relative to "domains" not objects from database...but in my work a lot of guys do this way
